# Formula returns 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a code that gives an error:

```py
from math import sqrt 

def normal(vector):
    sum = 0
    for i in vector:
        sum = sum + (i**2)
        norm = sqrt(sum)
    return round(norm, 4)

def innerproduct(vector_x, vector_y):
    sum = 0  
    for i in vector_x:
        for j in vector_y:
            sum = sum + (i*j)
            inner_product = sum
    return inner_product

def distance(vector_x, vector_y):
    distance = 0
    for i in vector_x:
        for j in vector_y:
            dist = normal(i)**2 + normal(j)**2 - (2*(innerproduct(i,j)))
    return sqrt(dist)
```

the first two functions are working fine but the third one returns TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: Maybe you are calling `distance` with a int in argument, so there is an error in the for loop ?

Comment: Paste the full error message. And the code which calls the 3rd method.

Comment: TypeError (most recent call last)
----> 1 print("distance(vector_x, vector_y):", distance(vector_x, vector_y))
 in distance(vector_x, vector_y)
     20     for i in vector_x:
     21         for j in vector_y:
---> 22             dist = int(normal(i)**2) + int(normal(j)**2) - (2*(innerproduct(i,j)))
     23     return sqrt(dist)
in normal(vector)
      3 def normal(vector):
      4     sum = 0
----> 5     for i in vector:
      6         sum = sum + (i**2)
      7         norm = sqrt(sum)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

The error I got is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(distance([1,2],[5,6]))
  File "t.py", line 22, in distance
    dist = normal(i)**2 + normal(j)**2 - (2*(innerproduct(i,j)))
  File "t.py", line 5, in normal
    for i in vector:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Because in your function `normal`, you do a for loop on a int (`vector`).

Comment: I tried to add  in range(vector)  to avoid this error, but it didn't work.

Comment: your vector variable is a int, you can't iterate on it, and you can't use `range` on it either. In your function `distance`, when you are calling `normal`, you put `i` in argument, it's a int from `vector_x`

Comment: so what is the possible solution?

Comment: Put vector_x instead of i when calling normal maybe, but I don't know about your formula